# When is it useful to use "strict wildcard" in Haskell, and what does it do?

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, wildcard, strictness

I was looking at some Haskell source code and came across a pattern match with `!_`, the code is here: http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.0.0/docs/src/GHC.List.html#unsafeTake

```
take n xs | 0 < n     = unsafeTake n xs
          | otherwise = []

-- A version of take that takes the whole list if it's given an argument less
-- than 1.
{-# NOINLINE [1] unsafeTake #-}
unsafeTake :: Int -> [a] -> [a]
unsafeTake !_  []     = []
unsafeTake 1   (x: _) = [x]
unsafeTake m   (x:xs) = x : unsafeTake (m - 1) xs
```

I don't really understand how the "strict wildcard" works and why it's useful for this function (or any other function).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The idea is that `unsafeTake` (and `take` for that matter), when asked to return the first `m` elements of the empty list, it should return the empty list, no matter what the value of `m` is. But what if `m` is an expression that throws an exception? For example, it would be weird for `unsafeTake undefined []` to return `[]`. So we need to ensure that `m` evaluates to integer even if we don't care what is its exact value (for the empty list case of course). This makes `unsafeTake` behave the same way when it comes to its first argument, not matter whether the second argument (the list) is empty or not.

Comment: I suppose it worth mentioning that if you use `take` function with `undefined` as `n` argument then it is unlikely to catch error in `unsafeTake` function because `n` is compared with zero earlier, i.e. it would be evaluated earlier. But because `take` function is supposed to be inlined as much as possible (as comment says) then this check may disappear after some optimizations. That's why we need `!_` in `unsafeTake` as well.